# twoside making wrong margins

Tags: margins, double-sided

I'm using twoside on my article. The first pages in the report (Abstract and preface) has the correct margins (larger margins to the right for left-pages, and larger margins to the left for right-pages).

However, the margins swap when the toc begins, and remains wrong for the rest of the report.

Any suggestions? I don't know how to make a MWE of this problem.

EDIT: It turns out that the first pages have wrong margins, while the rest of the article has correct margins.

Comment: The *outer* margin is wider when the `twoside` option is used; `fancyhdr` does nothing about page margins.

Comment: margins are for holding the book without obscuring the text, not for binding, they are wider on the outer edges not the inner.

Comment: Is the outer margin supposed to be wider? I though it was the other way around. That makes more sense to me ... :P. When binding a article, it is more difficult to see the inner margins than the outer margins.

Comment: The binding offset is different. That is supposed to allow for the binding. The outer margin is normally about twice the inner margin so that the white space at the centre of a double-page spread is the same as that at the outer edges.

Comment: Without an MWE, it is going to be anybody's guess why the margins are wrong at the beginning. Are you fiddling with the page numbers at all?

Comment: There is a special binding offset? How do I use it?

Comment: @ROLF open up almost any book, ignore any paper stuck to the spine and you will almost always see the outer margins considerably wider

Comment: Thank you! I changed the page start number, and now the margins are as they should be.

So the twoside-margins leave enough space for binding? Or is it, like someone mentioned, a separate "binding"-option?  
  
*feeling stupid*

Comment: That sounds like the wrong approach, the odd (right) pages should have larger right margin. traditionally latex does not address the binding at all as whether or not any is needed, and how much depends on the binding method. gemoetry package allows some allowance for binding to be specified